# How can I install Detectplate Python package

Tags: python, pip, package

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage import measure
from skimage.measure import regionprops
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Detectplate

# The invert was done so as to convert the black pixel to white pixel and vice versa
license_plate = np.invert(Detectplate.plate_like_objects[0])

labelled_plate = measure.label(license_plate)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
ax1.imshow(license_plate, cmap="gray")
# the next two lines is based on the assumptions that the width of
# a license plate should be between 5% and 15% of the license plate,
# and height should be between 35% and 60%
# this will eliminate some
character_dimensions = (0.35*license_plate.shape[0], 0.60*license_plate.shape[0], 0.05*license_plate.shape[1], 0.15*license_plate.shape[1])
min_height, max_height, min_width, max_width = character_dimensions

characters = []
counter=0
column_list = []
for regions in regionprops(labelled_plate):
    y0, x0, y1, x1 = regions.bbox
    region_height = y1 - y0
    region_width = x1 - x0

    if region_height > min_height and region_height < max_height and region_width > min_width and region_width < max_width:
        roi = license_plate[y0:y1, x0:x1]

        # draw a red bordered rectangle over the character.
        rect_border = patches.Rectangle((x0, y0), x1 - x0, y1 - y0, edgecolor="red",
                                       linewidth=2, fill=False)
        ax1.add_patch(rect_border)

        # resize the characters to 20X20 and then append each character into the characters list
        resized_char = resize(roi, (20, 20))
        characters.append(resized_char)

        # this is just to keep track of the arrangement of the characters
        column_list.append(x0)
# print(characters)
plt.show()
```

I have tried installing it using pip but to no avail. This is for my final year BSC degree. My project title is vehicle anti theft security system which will recognize the vehicle plate and recognize the face of the driver.

Comment: You are supposed to tells us in your question what is this detectplate package.

Answer (score 0):

There is no package 'Detectplate' available on pip, so probably you are using someone else's code (https://pypi.org/search/?q=Detectplate&o=)

The best fit from searching through web is this script, in which there is also **plate_like_objects** variable: https://github.com/apoorva-dave/LicensePlateDetector/blob/master/DetectPlate.py

If so, you have to download this repository and import 'DetectPlate.py' into your code. Don't forget to add the reference to that repository or your work will be categorized as a plagiarism.